# Which is the best way to store more than 1mb txt file in oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Is it enough to store a txt file inside a varchar?Or should i need to use blob?I am having a pure txt file.How to store a txt file which is read from html filefield inside oracle database using normal php(BLOB TYPE).And how can i retrieve it.Should i need to use any conversion technique to store and retrieve BLOB?

Comment: You can put the file in a specific folder and store its path in database. which will increase the sanity of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum oracle table column size is 4000 bytes (4k)  so 1MB will not fit.

So yes.. you can use BLOB.. but a CLOB is probably a better choice.
If your column will be text only files, a CLOB column will allow you to do text searches on content.

In non-oracle environments you may have access to other more appropriate types.  ie in MySQL you get TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT

example.

```sql
CREATE TABLE file_store(ID NUMBER, filename VARCHAR2(255), file_contents CLOB);

INSERT INTO file_store VALUES (1, 'testfile.txt', 'sample text that would normally be imported');

INSERT INTO file_store VALUES (2, 'testfile2.txt', 'sample IMPORTANT text that would normally be imported');

SELECT * FROM file_store;
```

`ID   FILENAME       FILE_CONTENTS
1    testfile.txt   sample text that would normally be imported
2    testfile2.txt  sample IMPORTANT text that would normally be imported`

```sql
SELECT * FROM file_store where file_contents like '%IMPORTANT%';
```

`ID   FILENAME       FILE_CONTENTS
2    testfile2.txt  sample IMPORTANT text that would normally be imported`